# Pagination table tr add previous and next jquery

Tags: jquery, button, pagination, html-table

I have a pagination that works fine, but I would like to add the "previous" and "next" buttons to my pagination code.

What I want is this:

[image]

Here my HTML markup:

```
<table class="paginated">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>  
            <th scope="col">C</th> 
            <th scope="col">D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
...... many many more rows in <tr>...</tr> .......
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here my jQuery code:

```
$('td', 'table').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(i+1);
});

$('table.paginated').each(function() {
    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = 5;
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
    var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
    var $previous = $('<span class="previous"><<</spnan>');
    var $next = $('<span class="next">>></spnan>');
    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
            newPage: page
        }, function(event) {
            currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
    }
    $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
    $previous.insertBefore('span.page-number:first');
    $next.insertAfter('span.page-number:last');
});
```

Here my JsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xugej/1442/

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Where is your attempt to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to make previous and next buttons trigger "click" events on proper tab button:

```
$next.click(function (e) {
    $previous.addClass('clickable');
    $pager.find('.active').next('.page-number.clickable').click();
});
$previous.click(function (e) {
    $next.addClass('clickable');
    $pager.find('.active').prev('.page-number.clickable').click();
});
```

If you want to make them active/inactive appropriately we need some more logic there. Whenever table is repaginating, you need to check whether next and previous buttons should be make clickable or not:

```
$table.on('repaginate', function () {
    $next.addClass('clickable');
    $previous.addClass('clickable');

    setTimeout(function () {
        var $active = $pager.find('.page-number.active');
        if ($active.next('.page-number.clickable').length === 0) {
            $next.removeClass('clickable');
        } else if ($active.prev('.page-number.clickable').length === 0) {
            $previous.removeClass('clickable');
        }
    });
});
$table.trigger('repaginate');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xugej/1445/